# Differences between prismatics schema and clojure.spec

Tags: clojure

I have just recently started to learn some `clojure` and in order to make something like types (more like contracts) for validations etc, the go-to solution is a library named `schema`.

Recently I learned that `clojure 1.9` however will have something similar named `clojure.spec`

Can anyone please tell me the differences between them?
When should I use one or the other, pros and cons, etc?

Answer (score 4):

Eric Normand did this [comparison](http://www.lispcast.com/clojure.spec-vs-schema), but as already pointed out you should definitely check the [rationale](https://clojure.org/about/spec), and there is also the [guide](https://clojure.org/guides/spec) and a [podcast](http://blog.cognitect.com/cognicast/103) where Rich Hickey talks abouts clojure.spec.

Answer (score 3):

The spec rationale is quite in-depth, I would suggest reading it: https://clojure.org/about/spec after that feel free to compare it with any other library you may be considering.